# How to initial BooleanArray by specific size

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I have read [Kotlin doc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-boolean-array/-init-.html)

```
<init>(size: Int, init: (Int) -> Boolean)
```

Creates a new array of the specified size, where each element is calculated by calling the specified init function.

The function init is called for each array element sequentially starting from the first one. It should return the value for an array element given its index.

Common
JVM
JS
Native
(size: Int)
Creates a new array of the specified size, with all elements initialized to false.

Constructor Creates a new array of the specified size, with all elements initialized to false.

```
<init>(size: Int)
```

Creates a new array of the specified size, with all elements initialized to false.

Constructor Creates a new array of the specified size, with all elements initialized to false.

also try simple code

```
var booleanArray = <init>(30)
```

it still not working. any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the documentation, `<init>` refers to a constructor. You should replace it with the name of the class, which is how you call a constructor. In this case:

```
var booleanArray = BooleanArray(30)
```

Answer (score 3):

Tenfour04's answered your question about `<init>`, but just to be clear: wherever it talks about "the function `init`" it's talking about the `init` parameter in one of the constructors. This is a function which takes an `Int` (which will be an index in the array) and returns a `Boolean` value (which will be the value at that index in the array).

So you can make this extremely very useful array:

```
val oddNumbers = Boolean(100) { it % 2 == 1 }
```

which will pass in index 0, do `0 % 2` and get 0, which isn't equal to 1, so index 0 is set to `false`, then the same for index 1 which ends up `true`, and so on.

Or you can ignore the index and just set the same value for everything:

```
val allTrue = Boolean(100) { true }
```

All the array constructors work like this, so you can easily set a default value or fill each index with different values

Answer (score 1):

```
var booleanArray = BooleanArray(candies.size)
```

This is how I init dynamic array